# TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization) vs BatchNormalization

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Do BatchNormalization and TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization) have the same effect on sequential data (eg video) or not ? If not what's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the docs of [tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed), you'll notice,

```
>> inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10, 128, 128, 3)) 
>> conv_2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3)) 
>> outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv_2d_layer)(inputs) 
>> outputs.shape
```

Basically, the layer wrapped in `TimeDistributed` will be applied to each timestep. Meaning, in the above code example, a `Conv2D` layer is placed below all 10 timesteps. The same would apply to `BatchNormalization`.

Instead of `TimeDistributed` layer, if we apply a `BatchNormalization` layer directly, the mean and the variance would be computed for all the 10 timesteps as a whole.
Whereas, a `BatchNormalization` wrapped in a `TimeDistributed` layer will compute the mean and variance for batches of shape `( 1 , 128 , 128 , 3 )` i.e for each timestep.